# placing in the same page two abstract in different language

Tags: page-breaking, abstract

I'd place in the same page two abstract section.One created using my own language and one in english language. If I tried this:

```
\selectlanguage{italian}
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
```

but they are placed into two different pages

Edit:

this is my environment definition:

```
\newenvironment{abstract}{
    \clearpage
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}%
        \bfseries\abstractname
    \end{center}}%
    {\vfill\clearpage}
```

Comment: I'm using book class and even if abstract is not supported I created an environment

Comment: post edited...I add the definition of environment abstract

Comment: You have a `\clearpage` in your environment. This is the reason for the next page. Delete it and use it, if necceccary, in your code and not in the environment.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5657/typography-and-style-for-acknowledgments-written-in-different-languages

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That definition is good for one abstract only. For more than one I suggest something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\newenvironment{abstractpage}
  {\cleardoublepage\vspace*{\fill}\thispagestyle{empty}}
  {\vfill\cleardoublepage}
\newenvironment{abstract}[1]
  {\bigskip\selectlanguage{#1}%
   \begin{center}\bfseries\abstractname\end{center}}
  {\par\bigskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstractpage}
\begin{abstract}{italian}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{abstract}{english}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{abstractpage}

\end{document}
```

You are of course responsible that the abstracts are short enough to stay in one page only.

Comment: It doesn't work for `article` document class. Why?

Comment: @EdyJo You have to say `\renewenvironment{abstract}` with `article`.

Answer (score 6):

The `\clearpage` in the environment definition causes the page break. There are several ways to deal with that. I suggest a simple approach: take the `\clearpage` out of the abstract environment like shown (using your code): Replacement for the abstract environment definition:

```
\newenvironment{abstract}{
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}%
    \bfseries\abstractname
  \end{center}}%
  {\vfill}
```

Example for the application:

```
\clearpage

\selectlanguage{italian}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: yeah now it worked...

Comment: I should insert only a clearpage or a clearpage after the second abstract?

Comment: @Mazzy: Depends on what comes after the abstract page. If you need the pagebreak and it's not automatically inserted by your subsequent code (e. g. a `\chapter`), then use another `\clearpage` after the second abstract. `\clearpage` is similar to adding a pagebreak, but it performs some other tasks like shipping out figures.

Comment: As of this writing, I could only get this to work using `renewenvironment`, rather than `newenvironment`, because, obviously, `abstract` ia already defined.