# How can I write the title of the thesis before the abstract?

Tags: languages, abstract

I want to be able to write the **title** before the **abstract** in both, English and Spanish. on the same page. I want to be able to write it in English as well. Without hardcoding it, how can I achieve this?

[image]

[image]

I am using abstract.tex file which is as follows:

```
\newenvironment{abstract}

{\thispagestyle{empty} \cleardoublepage\null \thispagestyle{empty} \vfill\begin{center}% 
        \Large \bfseries   \abstractname  \end{center}}
{\thispagestyle{empty} \vfill\null }





\begin{abstract}

La presente tesis estudia dos instancias diferentes de teoremas inversos discretos, la primera relacionada con cuestiones de convergencia en la teor´ıa.

    
\end{abstract}



\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
    
The present thesis studies two different instances of discrete inverse theorems, the first one pertaining convergence issues in ergodic theory and the second one
problems of local distribution in number theory. \\


\textbf{Keywords}: 
    
\end{abstract}
```

Then I load/call the abstract.tex file from the main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,pdfa1,a4paper,online,oneside,openright  ]{book}

\begin{document}

 \makeatletter
    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \input{dedication}
    \input{abtract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not at all clear what the issue is. Besides, the `article` class defines `abstract`, so certainly `\newenvironment{abstract}` will not work. Please, make a self-contained example.

Comment: Well you are hardcoding `Teoremas inversos discretos` into the abstract env. Could you please make a single exmple. I have no idea how the first sniplet is related to the second one.

Comment: @egreg The issue is that if I put it the way it should be, the abstract appears in Spanish only.

Comment: @daleif Check the updated post. I want to be able to write the title of the thesis before each abstract. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should put it into a single example, instead of those `\input` additionally we don't have the file `dedication.tex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `babel` and `pdflatex` a possible solution is

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,pdfa1,a4paper,online,oneside,openright  ]{book}

\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70815/placing-in-the-same-page-two-abstract-in-different-language
\newenvironment{abstractpage}
{\cleardoublepage\vspace*{\fill}\thispagestyle{empty}}
{\vfill\cleardoublepage}
\newenvironment{abstract}
{\begin{center}\bfseries\abstractname\end{center}}
{\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumen}
\begin{abstractpage}
    {\centering \huge \textbf{Teoremas inversos discretos} \par \bigskip}
        \begin{abstract}
            La presente tesis estudia dos instancias diferentes de teoremas inversos discretos, la primera relacionada con cuestiones de convergencia en la teoría.
        \end{abstract}
    
    \vspace{\fill}
    
    \begin{otherlanguage}{english}
    {\centering \huge \textbf{Discrete inverse theorems} \par \bigskip}
        \begin{abstract}
            The present thesis studies two different instances of discrete inverse theorems, the first one pertaining convergence issues in ergodic theory and the second one
            problems of local distribution in number theory.
        \end{abstract}
    \end{otherlanguage}
\end{abstractpage}

\end{document}
```

[image: xelatex]

with `xelatex` or `lualatex` and using `polyglossia` the result is equivalent.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[11pt,pdfa1,a4paper,online,oneside,openright  ]{book}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}% An Alternative to Babel xelatex lualatex
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\setotherlanguage[]{english}
\def\captionsenglish{%
    \def\abstractname{Abstract}%
}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70815/placing-in-the-same-page-two-abstract-in-different-language
\newenvironment{abstractpage}
{\cleardoublepage\vspace*{\fill}\thispagestyle{empty}}
{\vfill\cleardoublepage}
\newenvironment{abstract}
{\begin{center}\bfseries\abstractname\end{center}}
{\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}    

\begin{abstractpage}
    {\centering \huge \textbf{Teoremas inversos discretos} \par \bigskip}
        \begin{abstract}
            La presente tesis estudia dos instancias diferentes de teoremas inversos discretos, la primera relacionada con cuestiones de convergencia en la teoría.
        \end{abstract}
    
    \vspace{\fill}
    
    \begin{english}
    {\centering \huge \textbf{Discrete inverse theorems} \par \bigskip}
        \begin{abstract}
            The present thesis studies two different instances of discrete inverse theorems, the first one pertaining convergence issues in ergodic theory and the second one
            problems of local distribution in number theory.
            \end{abstract}
    \end{english}
\end{abstractpage}

\end{document}
```