# How can I have 2 abstracts in 2 different languages?

Tags: templates, overleaf, abstract, journal-publishing

I'm using a template I found on overleaf to make journal-like papers. The given format only has one abstract, but now I'm required to present two abstracts, one in Spanish and one in English. How can I modify my template to use two abstracts without messing up the format of presentation?

Here's the link of it: https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-pisika/yyzbjxcpnctf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [placing in the same page two abstract in different language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70815/placing-in-the-same-page-two-abstract-in-different-language)